# GCC error message in outb macro

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler, osdev

I'm developing an operating system. So far, I've added an HDD driver to my operating system that uses PIO. Here is the code in `hdd.h`:

```
    #ifndef HDD_H_INCLUDED
    #define HDD_H_INCLUDED

    #include "includes.h"

    typedef uint64_t lba48_addr_t;

    typedef uint16_t ide_ctr_t;
    typedef uint16_t ide_disk_t;
    #define MASTER 0x1F0
    #define SLAVE 0x170

    void read_hdd_sector(ide_ctr_t ctr, ide_disk_t disk, lba48_addr_t addr, void* dst);
    void write_hdd_sector(ide_ctr_t ctr, ide_disk_t disk, lba48_addr_t addr, void* src);

    #endif // HDD_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is the file `hdd.c`:

```
    #include "includes.h"

    void read_hdd_sector(ide_ctr_t ctr, lba48_addr_t addr, void* dst) {
        outb(ctr + 6, disk == MASTER ? 0x40 : 0x50);
        outb(ctr + 2, 0x00);
        outb(ctr + 3, (addr >> 24) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 4, (addr >> 32) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 5, (addr >> 40) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 2, 0x01);
        outb(ctr + 3, addr & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 4, (addr >> 8) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 5, (addr >> 16) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 7, 0x24);
        uint8_t sig = 0;
        while(!(sig & 0x08)) {
            inb(0x1F7, sig);
        }
        for(int ix = 0; ix < 256; ix++) {
            uint16_t word;
            inw(0x1F0, word);
            *((uint16_t*)(dst + idx * 2)) = word;
        }
    }

    void write_hdd_sector(ide_ctr_t ctr, lba48_addr_t addr, void* src) {
        outb(ctr + 6, disk == MASTER ? 0x40 : 0x50);
        outb(ctr + 2, 0x00);
        outb(ctr + 3, (addr >> 24) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 4, (addr >> 32) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 5, (addr >> 40) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 2, 0x01);
        outb(ctr + 3, addr & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 4, (addr >> 8) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 5, (addr >> 16) & 0xFF);
        outb(ctr + 7, 0x34);
        uint8_t sig = 0;
        while(!(sig & 0x08)) {
            inb(0x1F7, sig);
        }
        for(int ix = 0; ix < 256; ix++) {
            outw(0x1F0, *((uint16_t*)(src + idx * 2)));
        }
    }

    #define outb(port, value) __asm("outb %b0, %w1" : : "a" (value), "d" (port))
```

However, I can't build it. For all of lines that look like this:

```
    outb(ctr + x, y & 0xFF)
```

I get an error like this:

> Inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'.

I've read similar questions where the problem is the `-fPIC` compiler flag that doesn't allow using `EBX` but I use neither `-fPIC` nor `EBX` registers. Here's the full build log:

```
    $ make
    /home/alexander/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c11 -Iinclude -g -c hdd.c -o hdd.c.o
    In file included from include/includes.h:10:0,
                     from hdd.c:1:
    hdd.c: In function 'read_hdd_sector':
    include/system.h:7:27: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
     #define outb(port, value) __asm("outb %b0, %w1" : : "a" (value), "d" (port))
                               ^
    hdd.c:6:5: note: in expansion of macro 'outb'
         outb(ctr + 3, (addr >> 24) & 0xFF);
         ^
    include/system.h:7:27: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
     #define outb(port, value) __asm("outb %b0, %w1" : : "a" (value), "d" (port))
                               ^
    hdd.c:7:5: note: in expansion of macro 'outb'
         outb(ctr + 4, (addr >> 32) & 0xFF);
         ^
    include/system.h:7:27: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
     #define outb(port, value) __asm("outb %b0, %w1" : : "a" (value), "d" (port))
                               ^
    hdd.c:8:5: note: in expansion of macro 'outb'
         outb(ctr + 5, (addr >> 40) & 0xFF);
         ^
    include/system.h:7:27: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
     #define outb(port, value) __asm("outb %b0, %w1" : : "a" (value), "d" (port))
                               ^
    hdd.c:10:5: note: in expansion of macro 'outb'
         outb(ctr + 3, addr & 0xFF);
         ^
    include/system.h:7:27: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
     #define outb(port, value) __asm("outb %b0, %w1" : : "a" (value), "d" (port))
                               ^
    hdd.c:11:5: note: in expansion of macro 'outb'
         outb(ctr + 4, (addr >> 8) & 0xFF);
         ^
    include/system.h:7:27: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
     #define outb(port, value) __asm("outb %b0, %w1" : : "a" (value), "d" (port))
                               ^
    hdd.c:12:5: note: in expansion of macro 'outb'
         outb(ctr + 5, (addr >> 16) & 0xFF);
         ^
    make: *** [hdd.c.o] Error 1
```

What's strange is that for the same code in `write_hdd_sector`, no error is shown. I've got no idea what the problem could be. How do I fix this error? Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of `& 0xff` try casting to a byte. I assume `lba48_t` is a 64 bit quantity and so doesn't fit the constraints.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! If you post an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Hm, are you sure you have the right order of your parameters? It seems a bit like you switched port and value. `outb(value, port);` is the correct order.

Comment: @Ctx At @Jester's request I have had 6 cups of coffee, but the order of the parameters to the macro wouldn't affect the fact that value and port for the inline assembler template are correct. No matter what order the parameters in the macro appear as, the inline assembly uses `value` as the source operand and `port` as the destination with the `outb` instruction.

Comment: Statement like `outb(ctr + 4, (addr >> 8) & 0xFF);` suggest he is putting the port first and the value second when calling (albeit with issue of anding the value with 0xff which is a problem per Jester) which is what the macro seems to want.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Ah, ok, I overread that and assumed the "default" libc outb, where the order is different.

Comment: Note that you don't even need the `&0xff`.  Ideally gcc would make code like `outb %al, $40` / `shr $16, %eax`  / `outb %al, $42`.  Your code at best gets gcc to shift in another register and `mov %somewhere, %al` before every `out`.  (Maybe taking advantage of `mov %dh, %al` and similar).  At worst, copies and masks after every shift.  If you write your constraints for the port as `"di"`, you can maybe save code-size by avoiding an extra instruction to put a value into `dx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I usually use the "Nd" constraint.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not related to the usage of registers, but rather to the size of the operands. See, you `typedef uint64_t lba48_addr_t;`, and your `outb` inline assembly directive has a requirement that both arguments fit into 32 bits. By writing code of the form...

```
outb(ctr + x, something_that_uses_the_addr_variable & 0xFF);
```

That condition can't be fullfilled, as `addr`'s type is `lba48_addr_t`, a.k.a `uint64_t`. In order to avoid future issues of this kind in the future, you should instead define `outb` as an inline function like this...

```
inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t value)
{
    __asm("outb %b0, %w1"
        :: "a"(value), "d"(port));
}
```